# Can you have SoundTrap recorders as carry-on luggage in a plane?

Tags: fieldwork, soundtrap

I will be travelling in the field by plane with a SoundTrap recorder and its hydrophone. It will be an international flight (USA to Canada) with Air Canada. I am planning to take this as a carry on luggage. Based on [Air Canada's website](https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/restricted-and-prohibited-items.html#/), it looks like I should be fine, but I just don't want to get stuck at the airport.

Did anyone travel with SoundTraps in a plane before and had issues with airlines companies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I once had a brief-case sized pelicase as carry-on luggage, with 14 (yes, 14) SoundTraps in it, travelling internationally and with several airlines from UK, via USA, and through to the Caribbean. I did not have written confirmation from any airline beforehand - I rode on confidence. I had a spec sheet of the devices printed out inside the pelicase. I wore a marine conservation related shirt, and came full of whale facts... good luck!

Comment: Ah good idea to print the spec sheet! Thanks Chloe

Answer (score 9):

My advice would be to call the airline direct and ask, just to be sure.  Make sure you tell them what is in the kit that could be an issue e.g. battery type.

Then, on the travel day make sure you have the documentation of the recorder with you, so that airport security can quickly understand what it is (makes your life much easier). And, have it already secured in a padded case so that it doesn't get damaged if they insist it has to go in the hold.

Comment: Don't just call and ask, get a written response, with sender details and bring it with you.

Answer (score 9):

I recently flew with 24 NCR18650 batteries for SoundTrap 600s.  I had them in carry-on and they were packaged in cardboard with electrical tape on both ends and did not get flagged or searched (SouthWest Airlines between California and Hawaii).  We had the soundtraps shipped via FedEx but I do not see any issue with flying with them

Answer (score 6):

A quick search gave me
[this link](https://blog.voltaicsystems.com/lithium-battery-policy-airline/) (No air canada in it, but may be useful for comparison)

So, I looked up SoundTrap which says : 12  NCR18650 batteries 3.7 V x 3.4 Ah so the total storage is >150 Wh, which is more or on the limit of most airlines.

Yes, best to check with airlines, if it is OK to have them inside Soundtrap or if it were better to take them out and store them in one or more separate containers.

Comment: I'll call the airline beforehand, thanks for the suggestion Walter.

Answer (score 4):

Have done this multiple times on Air Canada with similar equipment (hydrophones, speakers and amplifiers).  They only ever get truly excited by the batteries so you have to make sure to have amps calculated clearly on the battery itself. On last trips the batteries had voltage and wattage clearly labelled on the outside but I still had to do the math with the security guard to figure out amps.

Answer (score 3):

I fly fairly regularly with a Soundtrap. It almost always draws interest from security and ends up with them removing it and inspecting it. I have been told that there is an internal component that looks similar to something that security is trained to look for when it goes through the xray machine. In the end, it is fine and I have never had an issue getting it through security or into or or of any country I have visited. However, if you are transporting between countries, I would look into getting a carnet for any equipment you are bringing. Twice I have had problems with customs because of equipment coming into a foreign country for research work.